# Terminal ANSI colors does not work with Inline::Perl5 (Data::Printer)

Tags: raku

The following Perl 5 script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Printer;
my @a = (1,2,3,4);
p @a;
```

gives output:

[image]

(note the blue color), whereas this Perl 6 scripts:

```
use Data::Printer:from<Perl5>;
my @a = 1,2,3,4;
p @a;
```

gives output:

```
[
    [0] 1,
    [1] 2,
    [2] 3,
    [3] 4
]
```

but the numbers are not colored (as for the Perl 5 case above).

**System information**:

```
$ perl --version
This is perl 5, version 29, subversion 3 (v5.29.3) built for x86_64-linux
$ perl6 -e '.say for $*DISTRO, $*VM, $*PERL.compiler.version'
ubuntu (18.10.Cosmic.Cuttlefish)
moar (2018.11)
v2018.11
```

Comment: @raiph `use Data::Printer:from<Perl5> colored => 1` gives `Error while importing from 'Data::Printer': no such tag 'colored'`

Comment: @raiph. Should be the perl6 equivalent of `{ colored => 1 }`, not `colored => 1`.

Comment: @ikegami and con: Turns out the Raku equivalent of `use Data::Printer {colored => 1};` is `use Data::Printer:from<Perl5> kv {colored => 1}`. See [How do I turn the Perl 5 module Data::Printer's `show_tied` option off when using it in Raku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59556587/how-do-i-turn-show-tied-off-when-using-the-perl-5-module-dataprinter-in-raku/59556588#59556588) for more info.

Comment: @raiph, hmmm. That sounds like the equivalent of `use Data::Printer colored => 1;` Maybe it accepts both? But the docs say you should provide a reference to a hash Data::Printer

Comment: @raiph, Ah yes, it shows `use Data::Printer colored => 1;` being used later.

Comment: @raiph, "*The first `{}` block is just syntax sugar, you can safely omit it if it makes things easier to read*".  So my first comment was wrong (and so was your claim of equivalency.)

Comment: @ikegami What you've quoted refers to documentation of DP. It was written in the context of P5. The syntax rules shift in the context of Raku, at least for the import/use statement. See the Q+A I wrote for further detail. In my comment I could/should have written "a (candidate to become the idiomatic) Raku equivalent" rather than "the Raku equivalent", but `kv hash` is, imo, the nicest way to write code so that importing DP, while setting options in the import/use statement, works, and leaves the original DP doc still largely apropos when using it in Raku. I tested all of this with DP.

Comment: @raiph, I never said `kv {colored => 1}` didn't work. I said Raku `kv {colored => 1}` (a list) isn't equivalent to Perl 5 `{ colored => 1 }` (a hash ref), contrary to what you said in your first comment. Raku `kv {colored => 1}` is equivalent to Perl 5 `colored => 1`.

Comment: @ikegami `kv { colored => 1 }` in Raku is indeed not at all equivalent to `{ colored => 1 }` in Perl *in general*. I didn't (mean to) suggest otherwise in my comments above. But `use Data::Printer:from<Perl5> kv { colored => 1 }` in Raku *is* equivalent *in effect* to `use Data::Printer { colored => 1 };` in Perl. In contrast, IP5 converts a plain `{ ... }` *without* the `kv`, in an import statement, as specifying tags -- before DP has a chance to see it. So it goes wrong. See my above linked Q+A for further discussion. Please do comment there if that Q+A is unclear or seems wrong.

Comment: @raiph, True, but that's not a reasonable reading of your first comment given the comment to which you were replying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205222/discussion-between-raiph-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with [version 0.40 of `Data::Printer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) which is the current version on metacpan. If I install [version 0.99 from GitHub](https://github.com/garu/Data-Printer) I get colors with Perl 6 also. See also [this issue](https://github.com/garu/Data-Printer/issues/112).

I debugged version 0.40 a little bit, and it seems like the only difference between the call to `p @a` from Perl 5 version versus the same call from Perl 6, is that the Perl 6 call is called in list context, so [`wantarray`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html) returns true for the Perl 6 call, this apparantly makes `Data::Printer` turn off coloring somehow.

Comment: *"this apparantly makes Data::Printer turn off coloring"* : This comment was based on inspection of [line 230 in the source code](https://metacpan.org/source/GARU/Data-Printer-0.40/lib/Data/Printer.pm#L230). Where `$wantarray` is true and this truth value is established at line 152 in the same source. Thanks for asking, I will check this again.

Comment: I can confirm it is turned on in the case of the Perl 5 script: I inserted the line  `printf "Wantarray = %s\n", ($wantarray) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";` before line 227 and it prints "FALSE" for the Perl 5 script and "TRUE" for the Perl 6 script. The question then is why Perl 6 would call the routine in list context (there is no list on the left-hand side of the statement). Can it be a bug in the module `Inline::Perl5`?

Comment: Thanks. Also, sorry. I should have figured this out. "why Perl 6 would call the routine in list context" From [the IP5 README's **Call a Perl 5 function** section](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5/blob/master/README.md#call-a-perl-5-function): "Please note that since Perl 6 does not have the same concept of "context", Perl 5 functions are always called in list context." I recall niner saying it was hard for him to do anything else. cf https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5/issues/31 I'll post a comment there tomorrow unless you already have when I get to it.