# How do I turn the Perl 5 module Data::Printer's `show_tied` option off when using it in Raku?

Tags: perl, import, module, tags, raku

I've used the CPAN Perl module Data::Printer (DP) with Perl. It works great.

Now I want to use it in Raku code.

When I use the `:from<Perl5>` feature to import it and then run code using it, the annotation `(tied to Perl6::Hash)` is appended to the display of hashes.<sup>1</sup>

As [DP's CPAN doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) shows, this annotation is controlled by the option `show_tied`. I want to switch it *off* (set it to `0`) instead of its default *on* (set to `1`). Here's how I'd do that in Perl:

```
use Data::Printer show_tied => 0;
```

But when I try this in Raku:

```
use Data::Printer:from<Perl5> show_tied => 0;
```

I get:

> Error while importing from 'Data::Printer': no such tag 'show_tied'

How do I turn `show_tied` off when using DP in Raku?

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Perhaps this is because [Inline::Perl5](https://github.com/niner/inline-perl5) (which implements the `:from<Perl5>` feature) is doing something to enable smooth Perl/Raku interop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I turn `show_tied` off when using DP in Raku?

You must explicitly convert [`Associative`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Associative)s (eg `Pair`s) that are listed at the end of a `use` statement, that are *not* "tags", to a flattened list interleaving keys and values.<sup>1</sup>

The most direct solution is to *manually* write a flat list of literals, eg:

```
use Data::Printer:from<Perl5> 'show_tied', 0;
```

For a neater solution, see the **Using `kv`** section below.

## Injecting variables

Note that `use` statements are evaluated at *compile-time*. So if you want to inject variables in the list then you need to ensure that their values, not just their names, are also established at *compile-time*, before the `use` statement is evaluated. An unadorned `my $foo = 0;` will not suffice because the `= 0` part will happen at *run-time*. Instead you will need to use a suitable compile-time construct such as [`BEGIN`](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/BEGIN):

```
BEGIN my $foo = 0;
use Data::Printer:from<Perl5> 'show_tied', $foo;
```

## Using `kv`

The [`kv` routine](https://docs.raku.org/routine/kv#(List)_routine_kv) can generate the desired `'key1', value1, 'key2', value2, ...` sequence given a hash:

```
use Data::Printer:from<Perl5> kv { show_tied => 0 }
```

or:

```
BEGIN my %opts = show_tied => 0;
use Data::Printer:from<Perl5> kv %opts;
```

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> This answer built upon Stefan's explanation from [the issue I opened in response to the "Altering parameters in Data::Printer in Raku" SO](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5/issues/135):

> The solution is rather simple: use `Data::Printer:from<Perl5> 'show_tied', 0;` The fat comma `=>` is a `Pair` constructor in Raku while it's really just a fancy comma in Perl 5. Raku considers `Pair` arguments to be used for importing tags like `:ALL` (which is equivalent to `ALL => True`). To get around this and pass what Perl 5 code expects, just list the values individually.

In other words, this need for conversion is because Perl and Raku share the *notion* of *tags* ([Perl doc about "tags"](https://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html); [Raku doc about "tags"](https://docs.raku.org/language/modules#Exporting_and_selective_importing)) and (not coincidentally) idiomatically use the same syntax for selecting tags (`:tagname`).

Furthermore, using Raku, this issue of (the need to resolve) ambiguity between whether syntax is being used to specify tags or not applies to *all* `Associative`s used in the top level of a `use` statement, not just ones written in the form `:foo` but even ones written in other forms such as `foo => bar`, `{ foo => bar}`, `%baz`, or `{ %baz }`.

Comment: these 3 solutions don't work given the test example I gave  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55799219/altering-parameters-in-dataprinter-in-perl6 it still shows the incorrect output with all of the terrible `var` variables.  It doesn't look like this package even works in Raku.  It's a shame, in Perl it works wonderfully :,(

Comment: Hi @con. **1** It works for me. See [my copy of your test script, details of the system I run it on, and the output it produces](https://gist.github.com/raiph/cd53ef62373464aee1d4e7b8eac535d4). **2** When I run variants of your test script per the guidance in this SO, they also work as they should, turning DP options on/off as expected. **3** These results are essentially the same for me, HåkonHægland, and Stefan (IP5's author). **4** I think Data::Printer works in Raku and this SO is correct. **5** If you wish to discuss your problem further, please comment on my answer on your prior SO. TIA.